# Automatically change connection of VPN when accessing certain websites

Tags: network, vpn, tunneling

So I am quite new to VPNs, just downloaded and installed NORDVPN despite the latest admission of security breach for a trial period.
I am also running BitDefender TS on my computer.

I wanted to know if there is any way to automatically reconnect to server from another country when accessing particular websites?

I have BitDefender, and whenever I open a banking website it opens the safepay browser for me automatically.

I was wondering if I can configure NordVPN to do that in any way. I'm worried that if the banking website sees logins from different countries, it will red-flag my account. If I can configure it so that whenever I access the bank, NordVPN automatically changes the VPN location (or automatically asks me if I want to change) to my home country, then the bank wouldn't log some change of country and things would be alright

If I cannot do with NordVPN, are there other VPN's that allow that?

P.S.
I was looking at split tunneling but it seems to me that split tunneling is to choose between the original connection and the VPN, but I cannot choose between 2 VPN connections.

Comment: I use FoxyProxy on Firefox, it allows me to select a proxy for each URL if I want to.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Split Tunnelling and use a different browser, then simply allow one browser to be off VPN connection.

Use that browser to access websites with your clear IP.

As for NordVPN, I just spoke with a rep and... there's no support for Split Tunnelling, but there's a browser extension that enables the VPN only for the browser, effectively allowing you to keep your direct IP for banking and such on another browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TouchVPN from the chrome store. It has options to

1. Auto enable VPN for certain sites while not actively connected to VPN.
2. Exclude certain websites from VPN connection while actively connected to VPN.

[image: touch vpn]

[Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/touch-vpn-secure-and-unli/bihmplhobchoageeokmgbdihknkjbknd?hl=en)